# GAE Datastore Stub Issue

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing some unit tests for my Django app on Google App Engine. The tests use the datastore stub by calling `init_datastore_v3_stub` and store some test data in it. For simple models this works fine, but when I store a model `B` that is a subclass of model `A`, I only get results if I query for the model as `A`. Example code:

```
class A(db.polymodel.PolyModel):
    ...
class B(A):
    ....
B().put()

print A.all().count() # prints 1
print B.all().count() # prints 0
```

Note that in production both lines will print 1.
Any suggestions?

**Update**:
It seems that the problem is not related to the db itself, but to the PolyModel implementation. I noticed that `B._entity` doesn't contain the `'class'` value as it should, but contains `'_class'` instead. It looks like:

```
print B._entity # prints {... '_class'=[u'A', u'B'] ...}
```

That explains the result I got. 
When I manually set the `'class'` value, everything works:

```
b = B()
b._entity['class'] = b._entity['_class']
b.put()

print B.all().count() # prints 1
```

I will continue to investigate and update here when I find the cause to the problem.

Comment: You may be encountering eventual consistancy.  You need to rule this out before looking at other issue.

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffman for the comment. I tried adding `sleep(10)` before the prints and still same results. What more can I do to rule out eventual consistancy?

Comment: Get the key from the object that you have just put, then call get() and this will resolve the eventual consistancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, it was a bug in my code in which I accidentally overwritten the `name` attribute of each property to be the field's class member name, which is `_class` for the `class` property of `PolyModel`. This happened during the creation of the Mock models for the tests, that's why I didn't have this problem in production.